# Ruby on Rails on Azure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, azure

for a new project we have been given the option to use Microsoft's Azure for free. We are mainly working in rails. Are there any ways to make rails work on Azure and talk to MSSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use activerecord-sqlserver-adapter, from NougakuDo, for the rails environment on x64 Windows. NougakuDo can be found here, http://www.artonx.org/data/nougakudo/.

Answer (score 1):

A quick googling turned up [this](http://rubyonrailsinazure.codeplex.com/)

So definitely it can be done. 
But i am not sure how many apps are being built in RoR for deployment in Azure, considering more mature offering like Heroku.
Maybe you can abstract away the nuances of the deployment platform hence making your app easily deployed on Azure, EC2, Heroku or other such platform with minor changes.